# filter rows with any two keywords from a list

Tags: r

I have a list of keywords, and would like to filter the rows that contains any two of those keywords in the list. For example:

List: a, b, c, d, e

I would like to filter the rows contains a&b, a&c, b&d etc.

Sorry I have no clue how to do it. Would be really appreciate if anyone has any suggestions on it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to SO, Jinggggggg! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.